# 16 bit CRC generation with 8408 polunomial on 8 bit input data in verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I've 8 bit input data and I've to calculate cumulative CRC-16 for the incoming input bytes.Please help me in generating verilog code for the CRC-16 generation with polynomial 0x8408.

```
function bit [15:0] ecc::cal_crc(input bit [31:0] data[$]);
bit [15:0] rCRC = 16'hFFFF;
bit [31:0] payload;
begin
foreach(data[i]) 
begin
   payload = data[i];
   rCRC[0] =  rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[4] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[6] ^ rCRC[10] ^ rCRC[12]
             ^  rCRC[13] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] 
            ^ payload[2] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[8] 
           ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[12]
       ^ payload[13] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[17] 
           ^ payload[20] ^ payload[21] ^ payload[24] ^ payload[28];
   rCRC[1] =  rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[6] ^ rCRC[7]  ^ rCRC[11] ^   rCRC[13] ^ rCRC[14]                                  ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[21] ^ payload[22] ^ payload[25] ^ payload[29];
   rCRC[2] =  rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[6] ^ rCRC[7] ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[12] ^ rCRC[14] ^ rCRC[15]                                  ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[22] ^ payload[23] ^ payload[26] ^ payload[30];
   rCRC[3] =  rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[7] ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[9]  ^ rCRC[13] ^ rCRC[15]                                  ^ payload[0] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[23] ^ payload[24] ^ payload[27] ^ payload[31];
   rCRC[4] =  rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[6]  ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[9]  ^ rCRC[12] ^ rCRC[13] ^ rCRC[14]            ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[21] ^ payload[25];
   rCRC[5] =  rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[4] ^ rCRC[6]  ^ rCRC[7]  ^ rCRC[9]  ^ rCRC[10] ^ rCRC[13] ^ rCRC[14] ^ rCRC[15] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[21] ^ payload[22] ^ payload[26];
   rCRC[6] =  rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[7]  ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[10] ^ rCRC[11] ^ rCRC[14] ^ rCRC[15]            ^ payload[0] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[22] ^ payload[23] ^ payload[27];
   rCRC[7] =  rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[4] ^ rCRC[6]  ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[9]  ^ rCRC[11] ^ rCRC[12] ^ rCRC[15]            ^ payload[0] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[23] ^ payload[24] ^ payload[28];
   rCRC[8] =  rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[4] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[7]  ^ rCRC[9]  ^ rCRC[10] ^ rCRC[12] ^ rCRC[13]                       ^ payload[0] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[21] ^ payload[24] ^ payload[25] ^ payload[29];
   rCRC[9] =  rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[4] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[6] ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[10] ^ rCRC[11] ^ rCRC[13] ^ rCRC[14]                       ^ payload[0] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[21] ^ payload[22] ^ payload[25] ^ payload[26] ^ payload[30];
   rCRC[10] = rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[6] ^ rCRC[7]  ^ rCRC[9]  ^ rCRC[11] ^ rCRC[12] ^ rCRC[14] ^ rCRC[15]            ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[22] ^ payload[23] ^ payload[26] ^ payload[27] ^ payload[31];
   rCRC[11] = rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[7] ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[15]                                                        ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[23] ^ payload[27];
   rCRC[12] = rCRC[0] ^ rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[6] ^ rCRC[8]  ^ rCRC[9]                                                         ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[24] ^ payload[28];
   rCRC[13] = rCRC[1] ^ rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[7] ^ rCRC[9]  ^ rCRC[10]                                                        ^ payload[1] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[13] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[17] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[21] ^ payload[25] ^ payload[29];
   rCRC[14] = rCRC[2] ^ rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[4] ^ rCRC[8] ^ rCRC[10] ^ rCRC[11]                                                        ^ payload[0] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[2] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[6] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[10] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[14] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[18] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[22] ^ payload[26] ^ payload[30];
   rCRC[15] = rCRC[3] ^ rCRC[4] ^ rCRC[5] ^ rCRC[9] ^ rCRC[11] ^ rCRC[12]                                                        ^ payload[0] ^ payload[0] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[1] ^ payload[3] ^ payload[4] ^ payload[5] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[7] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[8] ^ payload[9] ^ payload[11] ^ payload[12] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[15] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[16] ^ payload[19] ^ payload[20] ^ payload[23] ^ payload[27] ^ payload[31];
end
cal_crc = rCRC;
end
endfunction
```

This is in my system verilog design. I'm driving 4 bytes of data; `32'h000000B0`. The expected result is `62BD` but I got `56F1`.

Can anyone suggest me to resolve this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You need show your efforts first. Then only somebody can help you.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.

Comment: @Oduru Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Generating CRC calculator code is (almost) trivial exercise in tracing which bits of input and previous CRC value go into every bit of resulting CRC value, and it is done by iterating CRC bit addition for every bit of incoming data word. You can use any programming language you know to create a script that would generate for you verilog code of the needed CRC generator.

There are some traps, however:

1. Direction of CRC register shift -- could be right or left
2. The way bits of data word go into CRC: could be least significant bit first or most significant first.
3. The way bytes of data word go into CRC (in the case you have more than 8 bits in data word) -- most significant or least significant byte first.
4. Initial value of CRC register (usually all ones)
5. Change of CRC value after CRC is calculated: could be inversion or bit reversing in a some way, for example, ethernet CRC have both.

For the case of wide data word, it could be profitable to have a pipeline of 2 steps, first you pre-xor data word, then xor all together into CRC register. This way every bit of CRC register has input only from single pre-xored data bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with the following code, and it works fine to me;

```
    function bit [15:0] cal_16crc(input bit [7:0] pkt_bytes[$]);   
      reg [7:0] d;
      bit int_lsb;
      reg [15:0] c = 16'hFFFF;
      reg [15:0] newcrc;
    begin
     foreach(pkt_bytes[i])
     begin      
           d = pkt_bytes[i]; //Data;
           $display("DATA:%0h",d); 

        c = c ^ d;
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        begin
           int_lsb = c & 16'h0001;
           c = c >> 1;
           c = c & 16'h7FFF;
           if(int_lsb == 1)
             c = c ^ 16'h8408;
        end

     end
     newcrc[7:0]  = c & 16'h00FF;
     newcrc[15:8] = (c >> 8) & 16'h00FF;
    cal_16crc = newcrc;
    end

   endfunction

There is certain condition that the data will be driven from LSB to MSB.
Hope this may helpful to others.

thanks,
mahesh
```